# Best way to get number of lines from command whilst still outputting to both Terminal and to file

Tags: bash, grep, output, tee

I'm currently writing a simple Bash script which finds lines in files which match the target string and outputs this both to the Terminal display but also to a file. The command at the moment is:

```
grep -r -n -F "myname" /Users/tom/Desktop/* | tee /Users/tom/Desktop/out.txt
```

This code works perfectly for what I want it to do. However, I also want to have a feature that when the command has finished, it will echo the number of results (lines) that were found to contain the specified string.

What would be the best method of doing this? I understand that using:

`grep -r -n -F "myname" /Users/tom/Desktop/* | tee >(wc -l)`

would enable me to get the line count whilst still enabling me to view the output in the Terminal, but, it would not allow me to save the output to a file.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Kind regards, Tom

P.S. The script deals with very large files so efficiency is very important.

Comment: Why not run cat file | wc -l afterwards?

Comment: @MrTux I forgot to mention, due to the size of some of the files the command is scanning, the command can take a number of minutes and doing this would be highly inefficient compared to a grep command

Comment: I don’t understand why post processing the output file is so expensive... then, why no two tee calls?

Comment: Considered `awk` for this?

Comment: If the result is so big, why are you writing it to a slow terminal?

Comment: @awk I haven't, no, what would you have suggested?

Comment: @thatotherguy The result is not very big, I am outputting to the terminal in order to give the user a sort of live update to what has been found due to the fact that the grep command can take a long time

Comment: If the result is not very big, then @MrTux's original suggestion also works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tee` accepts multiple filenames to write to:

```
grep -r -n -F "myname" /Users/tom/Desktop/* | tee >(wc -l) /Users/tom/Desktop/out.txt
```

If you want to

1. Write to a file
2. Write to the terminal
3. Capture the resulting number of lines

You can use:

```
lines=$(grep -rnF "myname" /Users/tom/Desktop/* |
    tee /Users/tom/Desktop/out.txt /dev/stderr |
    wc -l)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Works perfectly. What method would you recommend for extracting the final line count into a variable from that command?

Comment: That was not part of the initial question, but I added a separate suggestion for it

Comment: Thank you so much! Works absolutely perfectly. I apologise for the possibly unclear question

Answer (score 0):

One option is to run `wc -l out.txt` after the `grep | tee` command.

But you can also pipe the output of the `grep | tee` command to another `tee`:

```
grep -r -n -F "myname" /Users/tom/Desktop/* | tee /Users/tom/Desktop/out.txt | tee >(wc -l)
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using multiple `tee`s?

Comment: Thank you for your response, this works for me but I am going to stick with @thatotherguy response as I feel that it is more efficient. Thank you anyway!

Comment: @thatotherguy There is no benefit. I was writing the answer while you posted yours and I was not aware that `tee` accepts multiple file names until I read it. Learned something today.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using `awk` since you can match and count at the same time:

```
$ awk -v tgt='myname' '$0 ~ tgt {cnt++; print} END{print cnt " matches"}' file
```

If you want to write the matches to a new file and assign the number of matches to a variable:

```
cnt=$(awk -v tgt='myname' '$0 ~ tgt {cnt++; print>matches} END{print cnt}' file)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll give this a try in a minute, do you know of any differences in speed between grep and awk when it comes to dealing with such large files?

Comment: `grep` and `awk` are similar in speed. If you have a lot of matches, this will be faster since you won't have `wc` have to reread the matches.

Comment: Thank you for the information. This works well for me, however,  I think I will stick to the solution above as I am more familiar with grep.